# Two absolute values satisfy $|x|_1=|x|_2^t$ iff they satisfy $c_1|x|_1\leq |x|_2\leq c_2|x|_1$.

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $k$ be a field and $|\cdot|_1$, $|\cdot|_2$ be two absolute values on $k$. Consider the following propositions:

(1) There exists $t>0$ such that $|x|_1=|x|_2^t$ for all $x\in k$;

(2) There exists $c_1,c_2>0$ such that $c_1|x|_1\leq |x|_2\leq c_2|x|_1$ for all $x\in k$.

I know how to prove that (1) holds if and only if both absolute values induce the same topology. But two norms induce the same topology iff (2) holds. In other words, these propositions are equivalent.

I really think there should exist a simpler proof of this fact (with just some algebraic manipulations) but I don't know how. I appreciate any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

We assume that the field is non-trivially valued with valuation $|\cdot|$ defined on $k$.
Here is a sketch of a proof that proposition $(2)$ hold iff $|\cdot|_1$ and $|\cdot|_2$ define same topology on the non-trivially valued field $k$.

**Proof:** It's easy to see that If proposition $(2)$ holds then the absolute values define the same topology. For the converse, Let $|\cdot|_1$ and $|\cdot|_2$ define the same topology on $k$. Since $|\cdot|$ is a non-trivial valuation on $k$, $\exists$ $\alpha\in k$ such that $|\alpha|>1$ and hence $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\alpha|^n=\infty$. Then every positive real number lies in between two consecutive powers of $|\alpha|$. Since the two absolute values define same topology on $k$, $\exists$ $r>0,s>0$ such that $B_2(0,r)\subset B_1(0,1)$ and $B_1(0,s)\subset B_1(0,1)$ ($B_{\epsilon}(v,\theta)$ is the open ball of radius $\theta$ and center $v\in k$ with respect to the norm $|\cdot|_{\epsilon}$ for $\epsilon\in\{1,2\}$). For any $v\neq0$ in $k$, $\exists$ $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|\alpha|^n\leq\frac{|v|_1}{s}<|\alpha|^{n+1}$. Then $\left|\frac{v}{\alpha^{n+1}}\right|_1=\frac{|\alpha|_1}{|\alpha|^{n+1}}<s$. The $\left|\frac{v}{\alpha^{n+1}}\right|_2<1$ by assumption. Thus $|\alpha|_2<|\alpha|^{n+1}=|\alpha||\alpha|^n\leq\frac{|\alpha|}{s}|v|_1$. Setting $c_1=\frac{s}{|v|_1}$ we get $c_1|v|_2\leq|v|_1$. By similar methods one can show that $|v|_1\leq c_2|v|_2$ for $c_2=\frac{|\alpha|}{r}$. Hence we are done!

Comment: Oh, I am really sorry. I don't know if I was very clear but what I want is a direct proof of (1) iff (2) without using that (1) holds iff they define the same topology iff (2) holds.

Comment: It's okay @Gabriel

Comment: Dear @user466737, the user TANG VAN Luan from the other answer has a question. "I don't understand this: i) $|\alpha|^n\leq |v|/s<|\alpha|^{n+1}$, then $|v/\alpha^{n+1}|_1=|\alpha|_1/|α|^{n+1}<s$. $|\alpha|^{n+1}$ turns into $|α|^{n+1}_1$ and $|v|_1$ turns into $|\alpha|_1$. It seems that $|\cdot|$ has turned into $|\cdot|_1$. ii) The $|v/\alpha^{n+1}|_2<1$ by assumption. Thus $|\alpha|_2<|\alpha|^{n+1}$. Here it seems that $|\cdot|_2$ has turned into $|\cdot|$."

Answer (score 0):

There is no such an absolute value relation in Proposition (2).

---

My motivation comes from noting that the relation in Proposition (2) has essentially two cases:

- $\exists c > 0;\;|x|_i = c|x|_j,$ with $i\neq j.$ [Proposition (21)]
- $\exists c_1, c_2 > 0;\;c_1|x|_1 < |x|_2 < c_2|x|_1.$ [ Proposition (22)]

Suppose that Proposition (1) holds, namely $\exists t > 0;\;|x|_2 = |x|_1^t,\;\forall x\in\kappa,$ and we're trying to show that (1) $\Rightarrow$ (2).

- If (21) happens, one is led, by considering absolute values of products, i.e. $c^2|x|_2|y|_2 = |x|_1|y|_1 = |xy|_1 = c|xy|_2 = c|x|_2|y|_2,\;\forall x, y\in\kappa,$ even in case of trivial absolute values, to $c^2 = c\Rightarrow c = 1,$ i.e. the two absolute values are the same, i.e. trivial equivalence.
- If (22) holds, then, $c_1|x|_1 < |x|_1^t < c_2|x|_1,$ for all $x\in\kappa.$ But this doesn't hold, e.g. when $x = 0_{\kappa}.$

---

P.S.

- where do you get this Proposition (2)? I would be grateful if you tell me a reference.
- I saw this relation in [1] and [2] but they are for norm and metric. I observe that an absolute value is essentially a metric but it comes with the extra condition of $|xy| = |x||y|.$

---

Refs.

[1] [pp. 157, 158]{Analysis I, Herbert Amann}

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics

Comment: Dear TANG VAN Luan, I don't think your proof holds. I agree that proposition 2 has two cases but these two cases hold only *for a given x*. It is surely possible that for some x we have equality and for others we don't.

This proposition (2) is a well-known criterion for two metrics to define the same topology. (It is what is called "strong equivalence" in your ref [2].) Nevertheless, in my head two metrics were strongly equivalent iff they generate the same topology, which is not true (as in [2]). This shows that my two propositions are actually NOT equivalent. Thank you :)

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was wrong as I forced each case to hold for every x. But is Proposition (2) for an absolute value or is it just for a metric/norm as in [1] and [2]? Could you tell me if you have a reference for saying that is for an absolute value, please?

Comment: I came to your post as I was to show these two propositions are equivalent in terms of absolute value also, but by starting to study your post and before answering it, I learned from the book [Proposition 3.1.3, p. 55]{p-adic numbers an introduction, Fernando Q. Gouvêa} that the same topology indeed iff two absolute values satisfy Proposition (1), while [1] says that Proposition (2) is only sufficient for two metrics to have the same topology.

Comment: Before studying your post and learning the Proposition 3.1.3 from Fernando Q., I even doubted that Proposition (1) is just sufficient for two absolute values to induce the same topology but not necessary. And Fernando Q. gives me the final piece confirming that I was wrong and Proposition (1) is also necessary.

Comment: Let's be explicit. Your ref [2] says that if two norms are strongly equivalent, then they induce the same topology. In particular, prop 1 holds. Also, since absolute values are norms, the same holds for them. (Of course, the converse doesn't hold, as we've observed.)

Comment: It seems to me that you're right. When I was trying to show the two Propostions (1) and (2) are equivalent for two absolute values, I also thought that absolute value is also metric, thus Proposition (2) holds for absolute values also. But if so, your demand of a direct proof is at least still valid for the direction (2) implies (1) as (2) is sufficient and (1) is iff the same topology.

Comment: The thought that absolute value is a metric but with an additional constraint of $|xy| = |x||y|$ still makes me worry that Proposition (2) is not valid for absolute value. Though my thought sounds stupid.

Comment: I wonder if there is also an iff for general metrics to produce the same topology, i.e. a necessary condition.

Comment: In the course of my attempt to show the two Propositions (1) and (2) are equivalent in terms of absolute values, I even followed (2) to invent a condition that $\exists s > 0;\;|x|_1^{1/s} < |x|_2 < |x|_1^s.$ This condition turns out to imply Proposition (1) as it implies $\{x;\;|x|_1 < 1\} = \{x;\;|x|_2 < 1\},$ which in turn implies (1).

Comment: So, I wonder if it is possible to similarly show from (2) to directly deduce (1). And also if possible to find a proof by contradiction to show that (1) doesn't imply (2).

Comment: Actually, the other answer on this post shows that prop (2) holds iff both absolute values define the same topology. So indeed (1) and (2) are equivalent. This is true even though (2) is not equivalent to defining the same topology for norms (but it is for absolute values). Tricky... tricky...

Comment: I studied that answer also. But I couldn't comment to ask for clarification as not having enough 50 reputations.

Comment: If you would like, you can ask here what you want and then I'll post a comment there saying that you have a question.

Comment: I don't understand this:

i) $|\alpha|^n \le |v|_1/s < |\alpha|^{n + 1},$ then $|v/\alpha^{n + 1}|_1 = |\alpha|_1 / |\alpha|^{n + 1} < s.$

$|\alpha|^{n + 1}$ turns into $|\alpha|_1^{n + 1}$ and $|v|_1$ turns into $|\alpha|_1.$

It seems that $||$ has turned into $||_1.$

ii) The $|v / \alpha^{n + 1}|_2 < 1$ by assumption. Thus $|\alpha|_2 < |\alpha|^{n + 1}.$ Here it seems that $||_2$ has turned into $||.$

Comment: I'm reading [p. 101]{Real Analysis with Economic Applications, Efe A. Ok}, which is cited in [1].

If $||_1$ is a metric, then so is $||_2 = 2||_1.$ So, these two are equivalent, right? But restricted to absolute value, such assertion is not true because of the additional property of absolute values of products, i.e.

$\forall x, y\in\kappa;\;4|x|_1|y|_1 = |x|_2|y|_2 = |xy|_2 = 2|xy|_1 = 2|x|_1|y|_1\Rightarrow 4 = 2.$

Comment: That is, given an absolute value $||_1,$ then the metric $||_2$ that is given by $2||_1$ is a metric, and they, being viewed as metrics, induce the same topology as Proposition (2) is a sufficient condition for two metrics/norms to induce the same topology.

Comment: But $||_2$ is not an absolute value. Yes, I remember the point that led to my wrong proof that the equality does not necessarily hold for every $x.$ But let me save it temporarily to focus on my current thought.

Comment: So, I wonder if the same situation may occur also with Proposition (2), that is, (2) holds for equivalent metrics, but restricted to absolute values, it's not true. This sounds weird as absolute values can be considered as a subset of the set of metrics, right?

Comment: I would like to justify this as follows.

In Proposition (2), if given an absolute value $||_1,$ then it is also a metric/norm, and if a metric $||_2$ satisfies (2), then $||_2$ is equivalent to $||_1$ in terms of metric as they induce the same topology, but this metric $||_2$ may not be an absolute value as the set of metrics includes not only those qualified as absolute values but also other metrics.

So, I am returning to my thought, which sounds stupid, that Proposition (2) is not for absolute value.

Comment: Yes, one may say that if there exists an absolute value $||_2$ that is related to another absolute value according to Proposition (2), then they are equivalent. But, I wonder if such absolute values exist. It's true logically, but the assumption may be empty.